# Can't get clicked(date date) signal from Calendar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am new in Qt, I want to connect qml Calendar signal clicked(date date) to cpp slote like this:
main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
   title: qsTr("MoneyInTheBank")
   visible: true
   width: 335
   height: 500
   color: "#333"

   Item{
       x: 5
       y: 9
       width: 325
       height: 240

       Calendar{
           id: calendar
           objectName: "calendar"
           x: 4
           y: 5
           width: 318
           height: 230
           weekNumbersVisible: true

           style: CalendarStyle {
               gridVisible: false
                       dayDelegate: Rectangle {
                           gradient: Gradient {
                               GradientStop {
                                   position: 0.00
                                   color: styleData.selected ? "#111" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#444" : "#666");
                               }
                               GradientStop {
                                   position: 1.00
                                   color: styleData.selected ? "#444" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#111" : "#666");
                               }
                               GradientStop {
                                   position: 1.00
                                   color: styleData.selected ? "#777" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#111" : "#666");
                               }
                           }

                           Label {
                               text: styleData.date.getDate()
                               anchors.centerIn: parent
                               color: styleData.valid ? "white" : "grey"
                           }

                          Rectangle {
                               width: parent.width
                               height: 1
                               color: "#555"
                               anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                           }

                           Rectangle {
                               width: 1
                               height: parent.height
                               color: "#555"
                               anchors.right: parent.right
                           }
                       }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Calendar.h:

```
class MyCalendar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyCalendar();

public slots:
    void ShowShedulerWindow() const;
};
```

Calendar.cpp

```
MyCalendar::MyCalendar()
{
}

void MyCalendar::ShowShedulerWindow() const
{
     QMessageBox msgBox;
     msgBox.setText("Button pushed");
     msgBox.exec();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Calendar.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlComponent qComponent(&engine,
        QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QObject *qObject = qComponent.create();

    QObject *qobjCalendar = qObject->findChild<QObject*>("calendar");
    if(qobjCalendar)
    {
       MyCalendar *objCalendar = new MyCalendar();
       QObject::connect(qobjCalendar, SIGNAL(clicked(QDate)), objCalendar, SLOT(ShowShedulerWindow()));
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

And I have:
QObject::connect: No such signal Calendar_QMLTYPE_14::clicked(QDate) in ..\Economist\main.cpp:24
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'calendar')
Please tell what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QML's [Date](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html) type "extends the JS Date object with locale aware functions". The [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) itself represents a point in time (e.g. 01/01/2014 10:30:00). In order to express that in C++, we need an object capable of storing date and time. In Qt, that's [QDateTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatetime.html).

Thus, the signal that you connect to emits a `QDateTime` object:

```
QObject::connect(qobjCalendar, SIGNAL(clicked(QDateTime)), objCalendar, SLOT(ShowShedulerWindow()));
```

---

After answering this, I realised that [Calendar's signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html#clicked-signal) are documented as emitting a "basic" [date](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-date.html) type, which I don't think is correct, as that type is indeed equivalent to `QDate`. Somehow, you can still connect QML signals emitting a basic date type to C++ slots providing the type is `QDateTime`. I've created a bug report for the incorrect documentation here:

[Calendar's signals are documented as emitting the basic date type](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-42495)

Comment: it looks like that the documentation is still wrong (Qt 5.6). According to the documentation [1] date (QML) maps to QDate (c++). However this isn't correct and doesn't work, as Mitch has already mentioned. 

[1] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html